# not able to get node value by xpath with getNodeValue function

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy

I have an xml response like below and I'd like to use values according to D_OUT keys.

I tried getNodeValue("//alfa//*:D_OUT_X//value") and getNodeValue("//alfa[//key="D_OUT_X"]//value") but these both return null. Can you help?

```
  <return>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_X</key>
                    <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                    <value>0</value>
                </alfa>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_Y</key>
                    <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                    <value>0</value>
                </alfa>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_Z</key>
                    <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                    <value>F</value>
                </alfa>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_A</key>
                    <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                    <value>0</value>
                </alfa>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_B</key>
                    <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                    <value>0</value>
                </alfa>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_C</key>
                    <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                    <value>01.11.2020/31.10.2021</value>
                </alfa>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_D</key>
                    <type>NUMBER</type>
                    <value>0</value>
                </alfa>
  <return>
```

Comment: Please post a runnable code example. Are you using XmlSlurper or XmlParser ?

Comment: I'm creating an xmlholder for the alfa response and after this I get the response like alfaresponseholder.getXml() and I'm trying to get the value with alfaresponseholder.getNodeValue("//alfa//*:D_OUT_X//value")

Answer (score 0):

This will get the value using Groovy's built-in XmlSlurper:

```
def xmlString = """  <return>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_X</key>
                    <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                    <value>0</value>
                </alfa>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_Y</key>
                    <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                    <value>0</value>
                </alfa>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_Z</key>
                    <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                    <value>F</value>
                </alfa>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_A</key>
                    <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                    <value>0</value>
                </alfa>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_B</key>
                    <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                    <value>0</value>
                </alfa>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_C</key>
                    <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                    <value>01.11.2020/31.10.2021</value>
                </alfa>
                <alfa>
                    <key>D_OUT_D</key>
                    <type>NUMBER</type>
                    <value>0</value>
                </alfa>
  </return>
"""

myreturn = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
myreturn.alfa.findAll { a -> 
    a.key.equals("D_OUT_X")
}.each { 
    println it.value
}
```